# EXCEL; changing cells after another cell is updated on protected worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

**EDIT: works if i use ActiveSheet.unprotect instead**

ok if my worksheet is unprotected, the following works fine!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo Reset_EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D6:G6")) Is Nothing Then 'do the following if D6 is updated
Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    If Range("D6") = "No" Then
        Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    End If
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D7:G7")) Is Nothing Then 'do the following if D6 is updated
    If Range("D7") <> "" Then
        Range("D7").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    End If
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("e12:f12")) Is Nothing Then 'do the following if E12:F12 is updated

    Range("d28").Value = Range("e12").Value 'set d28 to date entered in e12
    Range("c23").Interior.ColorIndex = 36 ' reset color of cell c23


    If Range("e12") = "" Then ' do the following if e12 is empty
        Range("c39") = Chr(34) & "Do you work period?" & Chr(34)
    Else
        Range("c39") = Chr(34) & "Do you work beyond " & Range("e13").Text & " (approx. period)?" & Chr(34)

            If Date >= Range("e15").Value Then
                Range("c23").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
    End If

End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E32")) Is Nothing Then 'do the following if E32 is updated
    If Range("e32") = "Yes" Then
        MsgBox "Please have the client complete a MVA Questionnaire."
    End If
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E41")) Is Nothing Then 'do the following if E41 is updated
    If Range("e41") = "Yes" Then
        Range("d42").Interior.ColorIndex = 38
    ElseIf Range("e41") = "No" Then
        Range("d42").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        Range("d42") = "Not Required"
    ElseIf Range("e41") = "" Then
        Range("d42").Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        Range("d42") = ""
    End If
End If



Reset_EnableEvents:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

but when i protect the worksheet and allow only unlocked cells to be selected, and add a password to the sheet, the above cell background colors and cell values don't update

i tried adding the activeworksheet.unprotect and protect at the beginning and end and it still wont work!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo Reset_EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

'ActiveWorkSheet.Unprotect Password:="a"

`..... all the if not intersect

ActiveWorkSheet.Protect Password:="a"

Reset_EnableEvents:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

i also tried putting the protect and unprotect in each if statement and it still didn't work,

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("e12:f12")) Is Nothing Then 'do the following if E12:F12 is updated
ActiveWorkSheet.Unprotect Password:="a"
    Range("d28").Value = Range("e12").Value 'set d28 to date entered in e12
    Range("c23").Interior.ColorIndex = 36 ' reset color of cell c23


    If Range("e12") = "" Then ' do the following if e12 is empty
        Range("c39") = Chr(34) & "Do you work period?" & Chr(34)
    Else
        Range("c39") = Chr(34) & "Do you work beyond " & Range("e13").Text & " (approx. period)?" & Chr(34)

            If Date >= Range("e15").Value Then
                Range("c23").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
    End If
ActiveWorkSheet.Protect Password:="a"
End If
```

help??

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to `ActiveSheet.Protect` and it works